# Analog Input not going to Zero

Tags: arduino-uno, pins

Arduino Uno user here

I am building a project with 4 analog inputs A0 dose not work. A1 A2 and A3 work perfectly fine! But for last input when I connect to A4 or A5, then they do not go to zero. They are stuck between 400 to 900. Even when connected to arduino ground it gives 400 instead of 0.

Am I missing something here cause the circuit for A4 connected to A3 gives perfect input value. They both work fine as output. Same situation with A5.

Is there another way to get one more Analog Input without multiplex?

Thank you!

Comment: Circuit is simple... Just 4 potentiometer and 4 pwn leds.

Comment: I mean the circuit on the Arduino board.

Comment: A 0 is a normal pin. A 4 & 5 are also the i2c data and clock, but that only depends on if a shield is connected

Comment: What do A4 and A5 report when you connect it directly to GND? What sensors are you using?

Comment: A1 to 3 gives zero... A4 and A5 give 440 approx... All input connect to diff RC pass filters..

Comment: there is no shield connected to Uno.

Comment: You haven't set the pins to "Input Pullup" by any chance? And you haven't done a "digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);" ?

Comment: I did not... I used digitalWrite(pin, LOW) though.

Comment: Connect A3 and A4 together, then put a 1 kΩ resistor between A3 and GND, then analogRead() both A3 and A4. If they both give high values, this means A4 is trying to output something, maybe through its I²C interface, or maybe it has its internal pullup enabled. If only A4 reads high, then you have a really weird problem. You may have fried a portion of the input mux of the ADC.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code.